# Missing "Use a device" option to boot a live distro from usb on a Windows 8 (UEFI) notebook

Tags: windows-8, usb, boot

I have a new notebook with Windows 8. 
I need to boot a Linux live distro from USB disk. However, when I access the boot menu which I expect to be like the following: [image]

in Windows 8, the entry "use a device" is missing [image: enter link description here]

(please disregard the red frames, these are only screenshots I found on the web to show what appears on my monitor).

So, I have to edit UEFI settings, reboot the notebook, disable the UEFI boot and enable legacy boot in order to boot the live distro from usb.

When I have finished, I have to edit the bios settings again, disable legacy boot and re-enable UEFI boot in order to make the notebook being able to load Windows 8 again.

Why am I missing the "Use a device" entry and how can I make it appear?

Comment: Does the entry show up if you boot with the USB drive inserted? Also, what make/model laptop is it?

Comment: No. The "Use a device" entry is not shown. My notebook model is Acer E1 571.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add screenshots of your UEFI settings? Is there *nothing* in there to allow you to boot from USB without disabling UEFI and reverting to legacy BIOS mode?

Comment: I am unable to take a screenshot of my UEFI setting. Anyway yes, there is the option to switch from uefi to legacy boot. Simply I wonder why I cannot select "use a device" in the boot menu from inside windows 8.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my ASUS N56VJ-DH71 notebook. The solution I got from ASUS worked for me:

- Enter the BIOS setup menu by pressing and holding <kbd>F2</kbd> when powering on
- Switch to "Boot" and set "Launch CSM" to Enabled
- Switch to "Security" and set "Secure Boot Control" to Disabled
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and exit
- Press and hold <kbd>ESC</kbd> to launch boot menu when the notebook restarts
  (or you can enter the PC setting menu in windows. You should see "use a device")

Comment: Sorry, I haven't the "Launch CSM" entry. And the "Secure boot" entry is blocked to "enabled".

Answer (score 1):

On the Acer E1-571 I found that after enabling the BIOS password, you are then allowed to disable secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but still the same issue on Windows 11.

If you already have UEFI enabled, I encountered the same issue with Intel RST/VMD enabled, because the recovery, as the install image, has no drivers installed for it, so it can't see any disks, and has limited options.

So I had to modify the WinRE.wim from either the recovery partition, depending on where you have it installed, adding the iaStorVD driver.
For how to do that, you can either search how to:

- Mount the recovery partition, using diskpart
- Mount the .wim image from it on a local drive folder
- Adding the drivers to the .wim image
- Commit modifications to the .wim image and unmount it.

After a reboot everything works as it should